# Does general Lua runtimes optimize table lookups?

Tags: lua

Can tables used like namespaces expand their fields before running, to avoid **indexing tables**? I plan to use Lua's 5.3.3 compiler. For example:

```
local Types = {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3
};

print(Types.A);
```

Could this turn into:

```
print(1);
```

or something like (but probably better):

```
local A = 1;
print(A);
```

directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Lua will run the code as is. That's the cost of compiler's simplicity.
See the output from `luac`:

```
main <2.lua:0,0> (8 instructions at 0x235bb10)
0+ params, 3 slots, 1 upvalue, 1 local, 7 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] NEWTABLE    0 0 3
    2   [2] SETTABLE    0 -1 -2 ; "A" 1
    3   [3] SETTABLE    0 -3 -4 ; "B" 2
    4   [4] SETTABLE    0 -5 -6 ; "C" 3
    5   [7] GETTABUP    1 0 -7  ; _ENV "print"
    6   [7] GETTABLE    2 0 -1  ; "A"
    7   [7] CALL        1 2 1
    8   [7] RETURN      0 1
```

Comment: Hum, I expected that it'd detect namespace-like tables, and it is said that Lua is a fast and lightweight language, with optimizations.

Comment: It is fast. If you need even more speed, and if 5.3 version of Lua is not critical to you, you can try LuaJIT (supports Lua 5.1 api + some features from 5.2). It beats google's V8 in performance.

Comment: I've heard about LuaJIT before. I didn't know it had such optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Types` as a temporary table to resolve global names:

```
local Types = {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3
}

do
    local print = print
    local _ENV = Types
    print(A)
end
```

But do ponder on *why* you want this. Note the need for saving `print` before setting `_ENV`.